# SAS : how to test if a variable is numeric

Tags: sas

I'm searching for a simple function to tell me if a given variable of a given dataset is numeric or not.

I would like to use it like this in an if statement in macro language:

```
%if isNumeric(ds,var) %then %do ...
```

But I can't find any way to achieve this simply. Do you have any idea if this is feasible?

I know it's probably trivial, but any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You should also clarify if you are asking whether a variable is typed numeric (ie, stored as 8 byte floating point) or whether a variable contains numeric-valid characters (ie, "132" is, "12AR" is not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You recently edited your question so I thought I'd contribute with the following "simple function":

```
%if %mf_getvartype(sashelp.class,age)=N %then %put This var is numeric;
%if %mf_getvartype(sashelp.class,name)=C %then %put This var is character;
```

The `mf_getvartype` macro function is available in the SASjs core library [here](https://github.com/sasjs/core/blob/main/base/mf_getvartype.sas), and reproduced below:

```
/**
  @file
  @brief Returns variable type - Character (C) or Numeric (N)
  @details
Usage:
      data test;
         length str $1.  num 8.;
         stop;
      run;
      %put %mf_getvartype(test,str);
      %put %mf_getvartype(work.test,num);
  @param libds Two part dataset (or view) reference.
  @param var the variable name to be checked
  @return output returns C or N depending on variable type.  If variable
    does not exist then a blank is returned and a note is written to the log.
  @version 9.2
  @author Allan Bowe
  @copyright GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE v3
**/

%macro mf_getvartype(libds /* two level name */
      , var /* variable name from which to return the type */
    );
  %local dsid vnum vtype rc;
  /* Open dataset */
  %let dsid = %sysfunc(open(&libds));
  %if &dsid. > 0 %then %do;
    /* Get variable number */
    %let vnum = %sysfunc(varnum(&dsid, &var));
    %if(&vnum. > 0) %then
       /* Get variable type (C/N) */
       %let vtype = %sysfunc(vartype(&dsid, &vnum.));
    %else %do;
       %put NOTE: Variable &var does not exist in &libds;
       %let vtype = %str( );
    %end;
  %end;
  %else %put dataset &libds not opened! (rc=&dsid);

  /* Close dataset */
  %let rc = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));
  /* Return variable type */
  &vtype
%mend;
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to know the actual type, and not the contents of a variable, there is a `vartype(dsid,var-num)` [function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p097vv7r6n97p9n15g2g5epgs7j1.htm) which has the exact specifications you need, excepting it takes `var-num` not `var-name`.  This example from the documentation should get you started; you can adapt this to use it to figure out a specific variable.

```
%let dsid=%sysfunc(open(mydata,i));
%let varlist=;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid,nvars));
  %if (%sysfunc(vartype(&dsid,&i)) = N) %then
     %let varlist=&varlist %sysfunc(varname
                                 (&dsid,&i));
%end;
%let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid));
```

Comment: What if the type of the variable is alphabetic, but the content is a number? What we can do if we want to know is the content is a number?

Comment: That's a different question, and you should ask it as one!  Though you might look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993089/logical-function-in-sas-to-determine-if-a-particular-value-of-a-variable-is-nume) first.

Comment: OK! Thanks. I saw the link. The Perl regular expression can be a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

In Data Step using vtype function, we can also determine the type of a give variable from a dataset.

```
data _NULL_;
  set  sashelp.class (obs=1);
  call symput('numvar',ifc(vtype(sex)='N','YES','NO' ));
run;
%put |&numvar|;
```

or, instead of call symput, we may use the following statement for elsewhere purposes.

`if ifc(vtype(sex)='N','YES','NO' )='YES';`